# Spring security not detecting the out of user from pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I really do not know how I posse my question.
I developed a web application and I used the framework (Spring,SpringSecurity)

the application works fine, authentication and management roles and privileges as well.

```
    <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pagess/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pagess/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_VISTEUR')" />
        <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsf"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.jsf" default-target-url="/Menu.jsf" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsf" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
            invalidate-session="true" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/interdit.jsf"/>                                       
        <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsf">
            <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </sec:session-management>
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="DataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
              select username,password, enabled 
              from utilisateur where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="
              select username, authority from utilisateur 
              where username =?  " />

        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

but that's just today I noticed something odd. while I'm in the pages I press the arrow previous google chrome up out of the application to the authentication page ,.
Just after I pulled in opposite sense flech Advent it allowed me to get to the application but it is not normal that without authentifcation.

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
     /WEB-INF/application.xml
     /WEB-INF/spring_sec.xml
      </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
   </listener>

   <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener> 
<listener-class>
org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class> 
</listener>

   <listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Haw can I do .thank you in advance

Comment: Just to clarify on the problem: You authenticated yourself. Then navigated back to a previous page using your browser navigation. And then after going back to the page needing authentication you where stil logged on. Is that about right? And what exactly is it you want it to do?

Comment: yes this is My problem he pass the login page without fill out the username and password

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh. What you described sounds like standard behaviour. After logging in to the web app a session with a security context is created and the user is from there on regarded as authenticated. A simple navigation away from the website in the browser cache won't invalidate the session. As it would be pretty inconvenient and would require the user to log in on every navigation to a new site. So this how the web app is supposed to behave!

To log out a user you have to either use the `j_spring_security_logout`, invalidate the session, delete the authentication in the security context or time out the session. None of these seem feasible in a case of simple browser navigation.

However to implement a app without a session you would have to set the session time out to a very low interval, or delete the authentication object directly after loading the page. Which is usualy not a very user friendly approach. For a better answer you might have to elaborate on the problem (which is so far not really a problem) a bit more, detailing what exactly the app should accomplish.

Comment: tank you @Carsten for your help .this is My logoutMethod                  public String dologout() throws IOException {
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
  .invalidateSession();
        this.username = "";
        this.password = "";
     ExternalContext context =FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
     context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath()
    + "/j_spring_security_logout");
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
  return null;
     
    }

Comment: But also after logout When I return back with prvious button google chrome it allow me to acces to application

Comment: Again there is no problem with that and nothing your app could do about it, since when you use the browser navigation a localy cached instance of the page displayed is used without ever sending any request to your server. But since any action on this page should trigger an not authenticated exception or something similar this is no problem. (Have you tried any actions on the cached page? What happens?)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsf" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        invalidate-session="true" />
```

by

```
<sec:logout logout-url="/login.jsf" logout-success-url="/login.jsf" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        invalidate-session="true" />
```

but I am not sure if putting **/login.jsf** for the login and at the same time the logout will work.

you may want to user `/logout.jsf` for the `logout-url`, you wont need to create a logount.jsf, and users will be able to logout using `/logout.jsf`

Comment: Well this might solve the actual "problem" at hand. But what happens when instead of navigating back the user just navigates somewhere else and then back to the web app? From what i understand it is not so much about logging the user out in a planned manner than that after leaving the web page the user stays logged in. After all Adriano stated that spring security is working well so far.

Comment: the spring-securty works very well. you can set the session idle time in you web.xml, which means afer an amount of inactivity of that time, the user session will be invalid. Now, when a user get to any page, if he as a valid session (and the right), he will get the page, if he doesnt have a session , he will be redirected to the login page. If the back url point to the login page, and he already has a session he will be redirected to your default url defined in default-target-url which is Menu.jsf

Comment: sorry for the delay I am truly grateful for your help